# onClick on custom text view not working on android version less than 5

Tags: android

To use my font, I used Costume TextView with the following code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BNazanin.ttf");
        setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }


}
```

and on layout :

```
<... .CustomTextView
       ...
        android:onClick="loadongallery"
         />
```

and on activity :

```
public void loadongallery(View v){
...
}
```

But by clicking on it on Android version less than 5, nothing happens.
I need both fonts and clicks, please help me.

Comment: What if you add the attribute clickable in xml ?

Comment: Add you **loadongallery** method code.

Comment: i use this method, public void loadongallery (View v){ ... }

Comment: please post your whole xml file and some activity code.I think it maybe click conflict or the view is disable or something?

Comment: Thanks, using (android:clickable="true") solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more attribute to the textview in xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```